# Putting variable in header = PHP

Tags: php, session

So I'm trying to make the posts.php page look like this >> 'posts.php?user='.$username << for each individual user.

Here is the code on my index.php page (which after a user logs in/signs up turns into >> 'index.php?user='.$username  :

```
<?php

include('header.php');

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))   {

    //do nothing

} else {

$_SESSION['username'] = $_GET['user'];

$username = $_GET['user'];

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;

}
```

Here is the code so far on my posts.php page :

```
<?php

include('header.php');

session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))   {

    header('location: must_login.php');

} else {

    //idk what to put here

}

?>
```

I'm trying to get my posts.php page header to look like this >> 'posts.php?user='.$username

Comment: Your question makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: This is a terrible programming practice. I could just set ?user=admin and have admin access. DO NOT DO THIS. Learn basic authorization and authentication first.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would anyone know where I could find some reputable info on sessions? It's hard to wade through everything on Google and the PHP manual is slightly more advanced than my PHP knowledge.

Comment: This is probably the first code he's ever written. Either that, or he works at Yahoo.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are on day 1 of PHP learning. You are getting a lot of negative responses because your question isn't very specific. You aren't very clear about what is "not working." You should say what you expect to happen, and what is happening.

Here's my answer based on what I think you're asking.

Since the username would usually be gotten from a sign-in form, and sign-in forms usually use POST, you should probably do that. Use POST instead of GET.

included files have access to all the global variables in the file from which they are included.

File#1:

```
// index.php
$username = $_POST['user'];
include('header.php');
```

File#2:

```
// header.php
<div id="header">
<p>You are logged in as user "<?= $username ?>"</p>
</div>
```

The variable you set in index.php `$username` is available for use in header.php.

Comment: +1 for beating me and for having the same attitude to new learners that I do.

Comment: @leemo thanks. I am still a new learner at a lot of things and it's helpful when people can at least point you in some direction rather than just saying, "wrong, wrong, wrong, go away." Although I admit this question is comically nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so there's a fair few things you need to consider here, but we all had to learn once so I'll try and cover most of them.

Firstly (as @TrentonMaki has said): DO NOT USE USERNAMES IN URLs. If this site is going live, it is probably the most dangerous thing you can do, aside from printing out your passwords onto the screen.

You must read about authorisation and authentication before you continue.

Secondly, in the interests of learning: the `$_SESSION` super-global is not the right one to use for URL variables. We call URL variables "GET" variables and therefore they are accessible like this:

```
$user = mb_convert_encoding($_GET['myVar'], ‘UTF-8′, ‘UTF-8′);
$user = htmlentities($user, ENT_QUOTES, ‘UTF-8′);
```

These functions 'escape' the data in the variables to make them safe from XSS and SQL Injection attacks (there are alot of other precautions you need to take as well - but they are outside of the scope of this question).

In terms of Sessions, these are variables that are stored in the **server** memory and persist between pages. there are several considerations when using Sessions (security vulnerabilties like "Session Hijacking") and things you can do to make Sessions safer, but here is how they basically work.

```
//start the session to retrieve or set variables
session_start();
//you should regenerate session_id here - you need to look up how to do this and other Session santisation.
//set a session var
$_SESSION['myVar'] = "myString";
```

Now when a new page is loaded you can get the value of a `$_SESSION` var:

```
//start the session to retrieve or set variables
session_start();
//you should regenerate session_id here - you need to look up how to do this and other Session santisation.
//get a session var
$myVar = $_SESSION['myVar'];
```

Some other topics you should definitely learn before you go any further:

- [mysqli extension](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) - do not use the mysql functions - this is by far the most common mistake new PHP developers make
- [Prepared statements](http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/) - these are a MUST for live data security. You should learn them so you never use anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Note :

1.Passing Variable above included file will passing variable to all included script

2.session_start(); must ONLY ONTOP of script and call only session_start(); to avoid session already started error.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username = $_POST['user'];
include('header.php');

?>
```